# Sending messages works fine in Chrome, fails in Firefox and IE

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, signalr

I'm using SignalR to send messages in real time updates towards my clients.

**Receiving** messages works fine in in Chrome, Firefox and IE. Meaning, I can send something from my Hub from my server and it reaches the clients without issue.

```
public void Receive(string whatever)
{
    // This correctly invokes a function on the clients end.
    Client.sayHello("Test");     
}
```

**Sending** a message from the client to the server does not work in both Firefox and IE, but works fine on Google Chrome 21.

On Firefox, using Firebug's Console these are the sequence of events fired as soon as the page is loaded:

```
GET http://localhost:12962/signalr/signalr/negotiate?_=1348547579430 200 OK 12ms
POST http://localhost:12962/signalr/signalr/send?transport=serverSentEvents&connectionId=b6fdd67f-6a71-4e5f-80cf-9e2b90cc7fe3 200 OK
```

On Google Chrome, that POST is never invoked maybe that's why it works there. All I see is a POST for `negotiate` and `connect`. Which is what I've come to expect after following tutorials and whatnot ever since [SignalR came out](http://lostinthegc.wordpress.com/2011/09/01/signalr-with-mvc3-chat-app-build-asynchronous-real-time-persistant-connection-websites/)!

On Firefox every time I click the button that's supposed to send off a message towards the server, this is logged in the Console:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
     var chat = $.connection.chat;

    /* Actions when someone clicks the Bid button. */
    $(".pujar").click(function () {
        chat.receive($(this).siblings('.auction-id').text());
        $(this).parent().siblings('.seconds').text('15');
    });

    chat.updateAuction = function (message) {
        var result = $.parseJSON(message);

        var divId = "#" + result.AuctionId;
        $(divId + " .seconds").text("15");
        $(divId + " .stat .amount").html("$" + result.LanceCost);
        $(divId + " .stat .latestbidder").html(result.LatestBidder);
        $(divId + " .stat").fadeOut().fadeIn();
    };

    $.connection.hub.start();
});

POST http://localhost:12962/signalr/signalr/send?transport=serverSentEvents&connectionId=b6fdd67f-6a71-4e5f-80cf-9e2b90cc7fe3 200 OK 16ms

Params
connectionId    b6fdd67f-6a71-4e5f-80cf-9e2b90cc7fe3
transport   serverSentEvents

Post
data    {"hub":"chat","method":"Receive","args":["1"],"state":{},"id":1}

Response
{"State":{},"Result":null,"Id":"1","Error":null,"StackTrace":null}
```

Any ideas what's causing this very weird issue?

Comment: What is your javascript code for the click handler?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could be triggering the "send" to the server before the connection has been started.

Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
     var chat = $.connection.chat;    

    chat.updateAuction = function (message) {
        var result = $.parseJSON(message);

        var divId = "#" + result.AuctionId;
        $(divId + " .seconds").text("15");
        $(divId + " .stat .amount").html("$" + result.LanceCost);
        $(divId + " .stat .latestbidder").html(result.LatestBidder);
        $(divId + " .stat").fadeOut().fadeIn();
    };

    $.connection.hub.start().done(function() {
        /* Wire up click event after the connection has been started */
        $(".pujar").click(function () {
            chat.receive($(this).siblings('.auction-id').text());
            $(this).parent().siblings('.seconds').text('15');
        });
    });
});
```

Note that for your server side code you didn't provide a "sayHello" function on the client so I'm assuming you just did not include that in your snippet.  Also Client should be Clients.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue today.  My issue turned out to be I was passing the hub an update (database change) on a jquery click event, then setting the click event to resume it's default action (which changed the current page).  After some good advice from a co-worker, I moved those events to document.ready on the receiving page and it fixed the issue I was seeing.  Chrome must wait for those requests to complete while Firefox and IE kills them if they take too long.